# How to install CRM 2016 Required Components without internet access

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2, prerequisites, dynamics-crm-2016

I am installing Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 (Full Server Role) on an isolated Windows Server 2012 R2 which doesn't have internet access. This is a constraint I have to deal with so it is not even possible for me to 'temporay enable internet'. MSSQL 2012 is on a different box.

I've been able to manually download, copy the files, and install all prerequisites but two:

- Microsoft Application Error Reporting
- SQL Native Client

[image: CRM Required Components Image]

Where/how do I install these two remaining prerequisites?

Strange thing is I downloaded native client (and other SQL prereqs) from  [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065) and native client show in program files.

I've also turned-on "Windows Error Reporting" thinking it might solve the "Microsoft Application Error Reporting" prerequisite.

I've looked at the [Software requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx) and no specific *server role* is specified. Do I need to install the "Application Server Role" ??? This is the only thing I can think of for the error reporting.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I've installed the "Application Server Role" but unfortunately, this did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You MUST install SQL 2008 Native Client!**

So the answer was finally obvious. Even if the item indicates 'minimum version required' and even if CRM 2016 requires SQL 2012, installing SQL 2012 Native Client does not work! [You must install SQL Native client 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44272) (you may select only the native client from the feature pack). I installed 2008 R2 SP3 and the requirement was met.

[image: SQL 2008 Native client install]

Finally once all SQL requirements are met, you may click "Install" to install Application Error reporting. This will install properly without requiring any downloads.

[image: Microsoft Application Error Reporting Installation]

Comment: No other answers submitted. Flagging this one as accepted.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Installing SQL Native Client 2012 doesn't work, the 2008 version is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2022:
In addition, you may need to manually install these:

SQL System Clr Types (SQLSystemCLRTypes\SQLSysClrTypes_x64.msi): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293645&clcid=0x409

SQL Server Management Objects (SQLSharedManagementObjects\SharedManagementObjects_x64): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293644&clcid=0x409